# Netbeans C++ Detecting errors when there are none

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, netbeans

I am using Netbeans for a c++ project. However, all the c++ includes/syntax(iostream, cstdlib, cout etc) are indicated as errors by Netbeans. I pointed the project compiler to g++ and the project runs fine, but I don't know how to make it find the libraries

Resolved:
Netbeans was just being dumb...restarted it and created new project...everything works...

Comment: My suggestion ; instead using netbeans, use GnuMakefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: Netbeans was just being dumb...restarted it and created new project...everything works...